# Manga where a martial artist steals a bracelet, causing his powers to be sealed and sending him to another world

Tags: story-identification, manga

The main character is a young man who looks like a cute young girl with hair all the way past his butt. The manga starts off with him in the Murim world as an unparalleled martial artist who lives with an all women group of Murim martial artists. One day a man shows up and the MC steals a bracelet from him and puts it on.

The bracelet seals most of his powers and then transports him to a fantasy world. There he fights off a bunch of orcs after receiving the dragon lord's sword from the dragon lord himself. A group of heroes including a human fighter, dwarven fighter, a human mage and a female elf try to save him from the orcs but end up watching in awe as the MC lays waste to them.

The MC ends up falling in the love with the elf and she ends up falling in love with him as well. Though he gets really upset when all the guys constantly mistake him for a cute girl.

Comment: Welcome to SciFi.SE! I'm glad to see you took my advice and reposted this here from Anime.SE. Hopefully someone will be able to find this before long.

Comment: You may want to explain that Murim relates to a sort of parallel world that exists in a lot of Manhwa (think wizarding world vs. mundane world in Harry Potter) rather than a term specific to this work.

Answer (score 1):

OP has confirmed [in a post on Anime & Manga.SE](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/61573/35679) that they were looking for a manhwa called *[Id - The Greatest Fusion Fantasy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Id_(comics))*. Just in case they never get round to posting it here as well, I'm making it a proper answer.

The manhwa follows a man named Ye Chun Hwa who, as per OP's description, is feminine in appearance and has very long hair. After being transported to a fantasy world, he takes the name "Id" in order to blend in. His travelling companions match OP's description as well: a human fighter named Grey, a dwarven fighter named Reindelph, a human mage named Ilran, and a female high elf named Irlina.